# Inverse of a peculiar matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Just encountered the following matrix:

$$ M = \begin{pmatrix}
c^1 e^{-i \phi_1 \cdot 1} & c^1 e^{-i \phi_2 \cdot 1} & \ldots & c^1 e^{-i \phi_N \cdot 1} \\
c^2 e^{-i \phi_1 \cdot 2} & c^2 e^{-i \phi_2 \cdot 2} & \ldots & c^2 e^{-i \phi_N \cdot 2} \\
c^3 e^{-i \phi_1 \cdot 3} & c^3 e^{-i \phi_2 \cdot 3} & \ldots & c^3 e^{-i \phi_N \cdot 3} \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
c^N e^{-i \phi_1 \cdot N} & c^N e^{-i \phi_2 \cdot N} & \ldots & c^N e^{-i \phi_N \cdot N}
\end{pmatrix} $$

where $c$ is some real-valued constant, and $\phi_k = \frac{(k-1)}{N} 2 \pi$ are the angles of the $k^{\text{th}}$ root of unity. It looks very close to a Vandermonde matrix, but not quite.

The question is: is there any trick to find analytically its inverse?

Comment: Hint: $M$ can be written as a product of a diagonal matrix and Vandermonde matrix.

Comment: Why is it not exactly a Vandermonde matrix?

Comment: @Greg Martin I always thought that it is a convention that such a matrix should start from zeroth powers, but looks like it is not true! (though I'm not a mathematician)

Comment: @Isomorphism thank you for the suggestion! Had a look at the general formula - it is quite cumbersome... (as I want to use the inverse further for some analytical formulas - the answer better be nice). I will try to check whether the fact that all $N$ entries are sqrt of unity gonna help.

Comment: @Isomorphism thank you once more! I figured this out, it is a DFT multiplied by a diagonal matrix. If you write any comment below - I'll mark it as an answer.